# jsonpath : How to access a key in current object when the key name is having "hyphen" in it?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonpath

Hi I am using the  javascript implementation of JSON path expression available at this  [link](https://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/)

From below JSON I am trying to get the list of objects from the "hyphened-key" array where the "inner-hyphenedkey" =1. I have tried using "**$.hyphened-key[?(@.['inner-hyphenedkey'] ==1 )]**" json path expression for this. But it throws error. Code is at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ScLm3/).

```
{
"nonhyphenedKey": [
                        {
                            "inner-hyphenedkey": 1
                        }, 
                        {
                            "innernonhyphenedkey": 1
                        }
                  ],
"hyphened-key": [
                         {
                            "inner-hyphenedkey": 1
                         },
                         {
                            "inner-hyphenedkey": 2
                         } 
                         {
                            "innernonhyphenedkey": 1
                         }
                ]
};
```

Please help how this can be resolved.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the javascript implementation, your filter expression (the `?(...)` block) is evaluated as regular javascript.  So you should use regular javascript in that expression.  Remember, `@` is a reference to the current node.

```
$.hyphened-key[?(@['inner-hyphenedkey'] == 1)]
```